# Installing Swampy on a Mac (OSX) using preinstalled Python version 2.6

Tags: python, macos, installation, swampy

I have the same exact problem outlined in this question:
[Mac Swampy (Python learning module) install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507915/mac-swampy-python-learning-module-install-help)

But I still can't seem to finds simple enough instructions to install and run Swampy on my mac. I have absolutely no background in computer science/programming and am teaching myself Python from Allen Downey's book "ThinkPython".

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me step by step, simple instructions to install the Swampy module on my Mac. Plea from a complete tech noob here.

Thanks in advance.

AJ

Comment: Someone needs to tell whoever created Swampy to make it easier to install. There's a lot of questions here asking how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

TO future programmers lost in the dark on this path, simply check out this wonderfully simple set of intructions by a prof at UCSB:http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs5nm/08F/ex10.html

- I was once blind, but now I see.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.